# How to set a generic return type

Tags: vb.net

I read values from a cell and the return is not fix. Instead of writing many functions for each return type I try to write a function with a generic return type but I stuck with this:

```
Public Function GetValueFromCells(Of t)(ByVal CellName As String) As t
    Return CType(_xlWorksheet.Range(CellName).Value2)
End Function
```

No matter what type I will find in the cell, I want to convert the value to the return type I set in the function. But all my attemps have been in vain. It would be great if anyone could help me get this accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since I touched VB.Net, but you should be able to do this:

```
Public Function GetValueFromCells(Of t)(ByVal CellName As String) As t
    Return CType(_xlWorksheet.Range(CellName).Value2, t)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would address a couple of things.

Use more descriptive Generic Type arguments and just declare a type of the Generic and return that.

```
Public Function GetValueFromCells(Of TCellValue)(ByVal cellName As String) As TCellValue
    Dim specificValue As TCellValue = Nothing
    specificValue = DirectCast(_xlWorksheet.Range(cellName).Value2, TCellValue)
    Return specificValue
End Function
```